# Rotated view doesn't rotate the volume button icon

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a OpenGL game that plays in landscape mode, when the use rotates the phone, I get a message via UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification and I render all my graphics upside down (via opengl transforms and rotates).

Everything works great, except that when the player pushes the volume buttons, the icon that comes up showing the volume is upside down when in UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft.

Do I need to tell the UIView or the OS that it was rotated as well?  Seems odd since I got the notification that it was rotated from the OS in the first place.

Comment: TBH, I think most games suppress it... I've never seen one. Granted, I don't play many iOS games.

Comment: That seems odd. The notification should be passed to all relevant views. Does your plist and settings allow for rotations?

Comment: I don't see anything in my Info.plist to deals with rotation one way or another other than UISupportedInterfaceOrientations, which is set to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight and UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft.

Comment: I tried it on a couple of games I've bought, and they all show the volume icon when you change volume and it is rotated correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the application's [status bar orientation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarOrientation%3aanimated%3a); I think that will tell the OS that everything needs to appear in a particular orientation.